# перемешивание списка в Ocaml

Tags: список, ocaml

Я ищу самый лучший вариант как написать программу в OCaml, которая перемешает элементы списка по следующим способу.

Первое число мы вынимаем из списка, и от других мы сделаем два списка, чтобы числа на четных позициях шли в левый список если будут меньше чем первое, и в правый список если будут большее. Числа на нечетных позициях наоборот пойдут налево если будут больше и направо если будут меньше...

Пример:
[6; 4; 8; 2; 3; 10; 7; 9] ---> ([4; 8; 2; 7])  6  ([3; 10; 9])

Спасибо большое за ответы!

Comment: что за _счетные_ позиции?

Comment: я думаю, что имеются ввиду четные и нечетные позиции :)

Comment: @ivg, да, похоже на то.

Comment: @Grundy Да, точно так, извините!

Answer (score 1):

При реализации этой функции мы можем воспользоваться двумя замечательными свойствами:

1. за четным числом идет нечетное, а за нечетным четное
2. по условию задачи, знак сравнения инвертируется на каждом шагу

Эти замечательные свойства позволяют нам отказаться от того чтобы хранить счетчик позиции и проверять его на четность. Мы начинаем с четной позиции и на каждом шаге рекурсии мы просто поворачиваем знак сравнения в обратную сторону. Для этого мы используем функцию flip:

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```

Таким образом `flip (<)` даёт нам `(>)`, а `flip (flip (<))` даёт обратно `(<)`. (Тут есть маленькая проблема с эффективностью, но об этом позже).

Далее мы можем реализовать функцию в точности с её словесным определением (даже проще):

```
let partition xs =
  let rec loop b cmp ls rs = function
    | [] -> ls,rs
    | x :: xs ->
      let ls,rs = if cmp x b then x::ls,rs else ls,x::rs in
      loop b (flip cmp) ls rs xs in
  match xs with
  | [] -> [],[]
  | x :: xs -> loop x (<) [] [] xs
```

На каждом шаге мы сравниваем, используя текущую функцию сравнения, значение из списка с опорным значением, и кладем его либо в левый список `ls`, либо в правый `rs`, затем мы применяем тот же алгоритм к оставшимся элементам, но инвертируем нашу функцию сравнения. Когда мы дошли до конца, мы возвращаем нашу пару накопленных списков. Мы можем их инвертировать, если хочется иметь значения в том же порядке, в котором они шли в оригинальном списке. Так как в условиях это не уговорено, я решил не инвертировать.

Наша реализация получилась достаточно эффективной, за одним маленьким исключением, выражение `flip cmp` каждый раз создаёт новую функцию, которая содержит ссылку на `cmp`. Если применить `flip` `N` раз, то мы будем иметь цепочку функций длиной `N`, которая в итоге приведет нас к функции `(<)`. И хотя нам кажется весьма очевидным, что `flip (flip f)` равно `f` доказаться это для компилятора не так просто, для этого ему нужно знать теорию функций, и ещё иметь возможность доказать, что `flip` не имеет никаких побочных эффектов. Новые версии компилятора, во многих случаях, способны это определить, но не в таком сложном рекурсивном случае.

Таким образом, если нас сильно заботит производительность (и мы доказали, что этот кусок кода действительно является бутылочным горлышком), то мы должны переписать `flip`, используя знание того, что мы имеем всего две функции: `<` и `>` и то что `flip <` эквивалентно `>`. Реализацию более эффективной версии, я оставляю читателю, в качестве увлекательного домашнего задания.

Comment: Красивая идея с `flip`!

Answer (score 1):

Ниже представлено решение с использованием стандартной функции `fold_left`, что позволяет явно не использовать рекурсию. Используется по сути тот же подход, что был использован @ivg, однако, здесь на каждом шаге инвертируется булева переменная (`even_pos`, принимающая истинные значения на чётных позициях) вместо инвертирования порядка аргументов у оператора `<`. Основная логика сосредоточена в функции `f`.

```
let partition = function
  | [] -> ([], [])
  | first :: xs ->
     let f (even_pos, (ys, zs)) x =
       let lists =
         if (even_pos && x < first) || (not even_pos && x > first)
           then (x :: ys, zs)
           else (ys, x :: zs)
       in (not even_pos, lists)
     in List.fold_left f (true, ([], [])) xs |> snd
```

Примечание 1: в исходном задании не очень понятно что делать в случае, если очередной элемент списка *равен* голове списка. Это вне зависимости от чётности позиции, т.к. у сравнения *три* возможных результата: больше / меньше / равно. При уточнении задания решение нетрудно будет доработать.

Примечание 2: порядок элементов в выходных списках обращён.

Примечание 3: голова списка имеет номер `1` (т.е. эта позиция нечётна).